# Solution of a homogeneous system is the null solution if it converges to $0$ for $x\to\pm\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ be diagonizable with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d\in\mathbb R$.

Show that: If $y\in C^1(\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^d)$ is a solution of the system $y'=Ay$ satisifying $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} y(x)=0$, then $y(x)\equiv 0$.

*Thoughts*: Let $v_1,\dots,v_d$ be eigenvectors of $A$ for the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d$. If $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$ for $i\neq j$, then $\{x\mapsto v_1\exp(\lambda_1x),\dots,x\mapsto v_d\exp(\lambda_dx)\}$ is a basis for the vector space of solutions. The condition $y(x)\to 0$ for $x\to\pm\infty$ implies that all components $y_i$ of $y$ must go to $0$ as well. These can be written as sums of exponential functions of the form $\exp(\lambda_i x)$ in each component, which implies that all coefficients have to be $0$ (using the linear independence of these functions) and thus $y(x)\equiv 0$. Why exactly is this the case, and how can one show this in the more general case where $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$ is allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $y(0) = \sum_k y_k v_k$ where $v_k$ are the eigenvectors.
Then $y(t) = \sum_k y_k  e^{\lambda_k t} v_k$.

Since $y(t) \to 0$ as $|t| \to \infty$ we must have $y_k e^{|\lambda_k t|} \to 0$ and since $e^{|\lambda_k t|} \ge 1$ we must have $y_k = 0$.

This is true whether or not the eigenvalues are distinct.

Comment: Thanks! You used the fact that -- for a basis $\{v_k\}$ of $\mathbb R^d$ -- we have $\alpha_k\to 0$ if $\sum_k \alpha_k v_k\to 0$. Why exactly is this the case? This makes sense in the static case ("$=0$") using basis properties, but why is this justified in the dynamic case ("$\to 0$")? It is obvious that it is true, but I cannot find a proof for this.

Comment: @st.math: A simple answer is that $\|\alpha\|_* = \|\sum_k \alpha_k v_k \|$ defines a norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and since all norms on $\mathbb{R}^d$ are equivalent, if $\sum_k \alpha_k(n)v_k \to 0$ then $\alpha(n) \to 0$. However, the result is true more generally (in that the $v_k$ are not necessarily in $\mathbb{R}^d$), see Theorem 1.21 in Rudin's "Functional Analysis" for example (this deals with complex spaces, but the proof is  value for a real space as well.